# Extract substring from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to extract a part of substring from string which follows as per below.

```
YY_12.Yellow
ABC_WSA.Thisone_A
SS_4MON.DHHE_A_A
```

I need to extract the string as per below

```
Yellow
Thisone
DHHE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
declare @tbl table (col nvarchar(100));
insert @tbl values ('YY_12.Yellow'), ('ABC_WSA.Thisone_A'), ('SS_4MON.DHHE_A_A')

select *
    , charindex('_', col2, 0)
    , left(col2, 
               case 
                   when charindex('_', col2, 0) - 1 > 0 
                       then charindex('_', col2, 0) - 1 
                   else len(col2) 
               end) [result]
from (
select col
    , substring(col, charindex('.', col, 0) + 1, len(col)) [col2]
from @tbl ) rs
```

I'm going to leave the full code so as you can hopefully understand what I did.

1. First identify and remove everything up to the dot "." (in the `[col2]` column in the nested `SELECT`)
2. Then I nest that `SELECT` so I can apply a new logic much easier on the result column from the first `SELECT` from which I only keep everything up to the underscore "_"
3. The final result is stored in the `[result]` column

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE app (info varchar(20))
INSERT INTO app VALUES
('YY_12.Yellow'),
('ABC_WSA.Thisone_A'),
('SS_4MON.DHHE_A_A'),
('testnopoint')

SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('.', info) > 0 THEN 
        CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX('_', info, CHARINDEX('.', info) + 1) > 0 THEN
            SUBSTRING(info, CHARINDEX('.', info) + 1, CHARINDEX('_', info, CHARINDEX('.', info) + 1) - CHARINDEX('.', info) - 1)
            ELSE
            SUBSTRING(info, CHARINDEX('.', info) + 1, LEN(info))
         END
    END
FROM app
```

My query, if `.` is not present returns `NULL`, if you want returns all string remove the `CASE` statement

Go on [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/86c4b/10/0)

Answer (score 1):

You could also try with `parsename(`) function available from **SQL Server 2012**

```
select Name, left(parsename(Name,1), 
                 case when charindex('_', parsename(Name,1)) > 0 
                      then charindex('_', parsename(Name,1))-1 
                      else len(parsename(Name,1)) 
                 end) [ExtrectedName] from table
```

This assumes you have always `.` in your string to read the name after `.`

Result :

```
Name              ExtrectedName
YY_12.Yellow      Yellow
ABC_WSA.Thisone_A Thisone
SS_4MON.DHHE_A_A  DHHE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, used `STUFF` here

```
SELECT  LEFT(STUFF(col,1,CHARINDEX('.',col),''),
                CHARINDEX('_',STUFF(col,1,CHARINDEX('.',col),'')+'_')-1
            )
FROM    @table
```

Output:-

```
Yellow
Thisone
DHHE
```