# Is there a ProstgreSQL string function that allows me to extract a substring

Tags: sql, postgresql

A column in a table has this string, how can I extract a first and last name.

{
"name": "Joe Smith",
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract substring from a string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185814/extract-substring-from-a-string-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

If it is really a string, you can use `split_part()`:

```
select split_part(name, ' ', 1) as first_name,
       split_part(name, ' ', 2) as last_name
from t;
```

Comment: my bad the datatype is jsonb.  The entire field looks like   {
    "date_signed": "07/26/2021",
    "signee_name": "joe smith",
    "signee_position": "test"
}

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always consistent with your example, then something like this would work:

```
    select
    regexp_replace(split_part(split_part(split_part(datablob, ':', 3), ',', 1), ' ',2), '"', '') as first_name, 
    regexp_replace(split_part(split_part(split_part(datablob, ':', 3), ',', 1), ' ',3), '"', '') as last_name
    from table
```

Where "datablob" is your column name. Using regex to replace the quotes with nothing. Perhaps shorter ways to do this, but it works...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using your updated example and not knowing the column and table names, you're looking for something like:

```
WITH extracted AS (
    SELECT (col_name->'signee_name')::VARCHAR AS name
    FROM table_name
)
SELECT split_part(name, ' ', 1) AS first_name,
       split_part(name, ' ', 2) AS last_name
FROM extracted;
```

Postgres has [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) describing its JSON functions.

I'm blindly casting to `VARCHAR` here and assuming simple whitespace based splitting of names.